# MVC 3 Returning multiple Flot graphs

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, flot

Thanks for reading. As I am ramping up to MVC, I am also getting more exposure to a lot of Javascript (which I am very weak in).

I have view that renders a list of data like below

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>heading 1</th>
        <th>heading 2</th>
        <th>heading 3</th>
        <th>heading 4</th>
        <th>chart</th>
    </tr>
    foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.data1</td>
            <td>@item.data2</td>
            <td>@item.data3</td>
            <td>@item.data4</td>
            <td><div id="graphname"></div> </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

By following the example from here http://blog.simontimms.com/2009/06/bar-graphs-using-flot-and-aspnet-mvc.html, I can get the proper data. How can I use what I have learned from that link, and also be able to create/return multiple graphs 
`<div id="graphname"></div>` 
since it is referrenced by the id? Or is there better way to do this completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set a unique ID for each div.

You can do this in a few different ways. Cleanest would be to tie it to your data somehow, eg if each item's item.data1 is a unique value (like a primary key) you could do the following

<div id="@("graphname_" + item.data1>"

Or you could add an index inside the foreach and refer to that

```
int i = 0;
foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.data1</td>
        <td>@item.data2</td>
        <td>@item.data3</td>
        <td>@item.data4</td>
        <td><div id="@(graphname + i)"></div> </td>
    </tr>
    ++i;
}
```

From there it's just a matter of calling $.plot for each graph, referencing the required data and the correct div